# Z3 optimization: detect unboundedness via API

Tags: c++, c, optimization, z3

I am experiencing difficulties in detecting unboundedness of an optimization problem. As stated in the examples and in some answers here, the printed result of an unbounded optimization problem equals to something like "oo", which has to be interpreted (via string compare?).

My question is: Is there any way to use the API to detect this?

I've searched for some time now and the only function, which might do what I want is `Z3_mk_fpa_is_infinite(Z3_context c, Z3_ast t)` which returns some `Z3_ast` object. The problem is: Is this the right approach and how do I get the unbounded property out of that `Z3_ast` object?

Comment: Z3_mk_fpa_is_infinite is a function to check whether a floating-point number is +oo or -oo (+Inf, -Inf), if you are not using floating-point numbers you won't need this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way to extract unbounded values or infinitesimals.
The optimization engine uses ad-hoc constants called "epsilon" (of type Real) and "oo" (of type Real or Integer) when representing maximal/minimal that
are unbounded or at a strict bound. There is no built-in recognizer for these constants and formally, they don't belong to the domain of Reals. They belong to an extension field. So formally, I would have to return an expression over a different number field or return what amounts to a triple of numerals (epsilon, standard numeral, infinite). For example, a standard numeral 5.6 would be represented as (0, 5.6, 0), and a numeral that comes just below 5.6 is represented as (-1, 5.6, 0), and a numeral that is +infinity is (0, 0, 1). Returning three values instead of one seemed no more satisfactory a solution to me as returning an expression. I am leaving it to users to post-process the expressions that are returned and indeed match for symbols "oo" and "epsilon" to decompose the values if they need so.

Comment: Okay and negative infinity is to be mapped to "-oo"?